# Is there a way to check DNS records to determine the creation date of a subdomain? e.g. blog.example.com

Tags: domain-name-system, subdomain

I need to determine when a subdomain was created. Is there a way to do that with DNS lookups?

For a given top level domain like example.com, can I find out when blog.example.com was created?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. Unless you specifically know someone who happens to have historical DNS records for the domain, there is no way to tell.